# KivyMD Layout - Add widget (from python) to existing BoxLayout

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I spent really lot of time with googling about probably simple problem but i absolutely i don't know where can be a problem...

I have simple *primaryscreen.kv* file with code:

```py
<ContentArea@MDBoxLayout>

<BottomBar@MDBoxLayout>

<PrimaryScreen>
    name: 'primary'
    id: primaryscreen

    content_area: content_area

    MDBoxLayout:

        spacing: 6
        padding: [10, 4, 10, 4]

        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 1.2

            MDLabel:
                font_style: 'H5'
                text: root.app_title


        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 5
            orientation: "horizontal"

            DevicesGrid:
                size_hint_x: 1


            ContentArea:
                id: content_area

                size_hint_x: 3
                orientation: "vertical"
...
...
```

And *primaryscreen.py* file:

```py
...
...
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                       "uix",
                       "screens",
                       "kv",
                       "primaryscreen.kv"), encoding="utf-8") as KV:
    Builder.load_string(KV.read())


class PrimaryScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PrimaryScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.app_title = "DeviceName"

        self.content_area.add_widget((MDLabel(text='aaaa')))
```

**Update (added directory tree and code in mainscreen.kv and mainscreen.py file)**

```
├── main.py
└── uix
    ├── __init__.py
    └── screens
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── baseclass
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── mainscreen.py
        │   ├── primaryscreen.py
        │   └── settingsscreen.py
        └── kv
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── mainscreen.kv
            ├── primaryscreen.kv
            └── settingsscreen.kv
```

*mainscreen.kv*

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    id: sm
    PrimaryScreen:
        name: 'primary'
        id: primaryscreen
    SettingsScreen:
        name: 'settings'
        id: settingsscreen
```

*mainscreen.py*

```py
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                       "uix",
                       "screens",
                       "kv",
                       "mainscreen.kv"), encoding="utf-8") as KV:
    Builder.load_string(KV.read())


class MainScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

And i dont't know **i can add my custom widget (in this example its MDLabel)** to existing BoxLayout.

Please, its possible? How?

I tried lot of combination (ids, ObjectProperties, MDApp.get_running_app().root)without success :/

Thank you for any ideas...

**Working solution** (but i don't know if is clear solution / best practice):

My file *primaryscreen.py* was updated to:

```py
class PrimaryScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PrimaryScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_screen)                    # <-- Added line

        self.app_title = "DeviceName"

    def update_screen(self, *args):                                # <-- Added line
        self.content_area.add_widget((MDLabel(text='aaaa',         # <-- Added line
                                              font_style='H3')))   # <-- Added line
```

Comment: Which widget do you want to add?

Comment: Hello @DYD In this case i want to add widget "MDLabel" created in *.py file to widget ContentArea created in *.kv file

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand your problem. What is it you would like to achieve? Can the Label not just be added to the appropriate KV file? Or does it have to be in a .py file?

Comment: @jda5 thank you for your interest. My goal is dynamicaly adding i.e. MDLabel widget from python file to *.kv file. When i tried `Clock.schedule_once(self.update_screen)` it works fine (updated code was added to bottom of my post) but i don't know if is it a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try employing the `on_enter` and `on_pre_enter` events (see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html)

I recommend trying the following:

```
class PrimaryScreen(MDScreen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PrimaryScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app_title = "DeviceName"

    def on_pre_enter(self, text: str):
         self.content_area.add_widget((MDLabel(text=text, font_style='H3')))
```

If this fails then try `on_enter`.

You can extend this by creating a function that adds a Label and then is called in `on_pre_enter`, i.e.

```
class PrimaryScreen(MDScreen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PrimaryScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app_title = "DeviceName"

    def on_pre_enter(self):
         self.add_label('aaaa')

    def add_label(self, text: str):
         self.content_area.add_widget((MDLabel(text=text, font_style='H3')))
```

Now you can add as many Labels as you like!

Does this help?

Comment: thank you for your support. When i try your second part (`def on_pre_enter ...` + `def add_label ...`) terminal show error `self.content_area.add_widget((MDLabel(text='text', font_style='H3')))
 AttributeError: 'PrimaryScreen' object has no attribute 'content_area'`. This error was shown in my last tries and after that i created this Question. Please, do you think that problem can be with my "larger" structure of app or why my `PrimaryScreen' object has no attribute 'content_area'`?

Comment: You could try `self.ids['content_area']` instead. Failing that try accessing it using the children property

Comment: I see different type of error `self.ids['content_area'].add_widget((MDLabel(text=text, font_style='H3')))
 KeyError: 'content_area'`. But same *.kv code with `Clock.schedule_once(self.update_screen) `  works fine (full code is in my question). Don't you think that i have problem with bit complicated app structure or multiple *.kv file?